# BIg Cartel: How to insert javascript code to close an image overlay in the "Roadie" Theme

Tags: bigcartel

[www.thefabtabs.com](http://www.thefabtabs.com)

My knowledge of HTML and CSS is woefully out of date (2003ish) and very rusty.  JavaScript is non-existent.  I'm launching a little Big Cartel website for some products I have been selling via Instagram and eBay. I'm trying to keep things fairly simple. I have the home image enabled with a text overlay enabled.  I am looking to close the overlay through JavaScript.

Using ChatGPT I was able to get the overlay to display through this HTML:

```
<div class="custom-block">
    <div class="image-overlay">
        <img src="your-image-url.jpg" alt="Image">
        <div class="text-overlay">
            <p>This is the text overlay.</p>
            <a href="#" class="close-overlay">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this CSS:

```
.text-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff; /* Text color */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* Background color with opacity */
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 18px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
}

.close-overlay {
    color: #fff; /* Text color for the close button */
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    font-size: 20px; /* Adjust the font size of the close button */
}
```

After a little tweaking I was able to get it looking close to how I envisioned it but I would also like the user to be able to close it.  This JavaScript was generated:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var overlayBanner = document.getElementById('overlay-banner');
    var closeOverlayButton = document.querySelector('.close-overlay');

    closeOverlayButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        overlayBanner.style.display = 'none';
    });
});
```

I don't know how to implement this part of the code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.